# how to debug module 'plotly.tools' has no attribute 'set_credentials_file'

Tags: plotly

***how to debug module*** 
4

I don't understand why this snippet of code does not work. The data is fictional, I just want to be able to make time-series visualization with plotly.

This module once worked for me in a Kaggle kernel :
https://www.kaggle.com/feiliang0307/a-cost-sensitive-model/notebook

but my python say

```
'plotly . tools' has no attribute 'set_credentials_file'
```

can anyone help me ? i am a beginner

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you have version 4 of `plotly` installed and the code you're running is designed for version 3.